# How can I create a function expr that doesn't inherit lexical scope?

Tags: javascript

The following JavaScript violates CSP (if the CSP has default settings):

```
(function() {
  return new Function('return function Thing() {}');
}());
```

But this alternative inherits its parent scope:

```
(function() {
  var foo = '42';
  return function Thing() {};
}());
```

Which I believe prevents `foo` being garbage collected.

Is there a way to place a function definition in the global scope (note that I don't mean access it in global scope, I mean its definition exists in global scope), if you're restricted to writing your code inside an IIFE?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve here, since the code you provided doesn't do anything of actual use. The variable `foo` will be created and assigned, and a function `Thing` will be returned, but as soon as the IIFE is executed, all references are lost and garbage collection will take place.

If I make the function a little more useful as an example, the following will generate the `thing` function, and the variable `foo` will still exist, as it is closed over - See [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
function generateThing() {
    var foo = '42';
    return function thing() {
        console.log("thing:", foo)
    };
}

var myThing = generateThing();
myThing();
```

If you don't reference `foo` in the inner function, the reference will not be maintained and it will be garbage collected.

If you use an object literal for your module, you can restrict scope using `this`. In the following example, the `generateThing` function references the module's `foo` field.  During the execution, that value will be available as it is in lexical scope. However, if you create an inner function, the context `this` will be different. Therefore, when you call the returned function, it will output `undefined`.

You can control the context of `this` using the `apply` function (among others). By calling the function with `myModule` as the context, we can reference the `foo` variable.

```
(function() {
    var myModule = {
        foo: 42,
        generateThing: function() {
            console.log("generateThing", this.foo);
            return function() {
                console.log("thing:", this.foo);
            }
        }
    }

    window.myModule = myModule;

}());

var thing = myModule.generateThing(); // log: generateThing 42
thing(); // log: thing undefined
thing.apply(myModule); // output: thing 42
```